# How do I include html in C# block and C# in html block in the following View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have my view here and it throws errors, either there is missing {} block or an "eternal components throws and exception" when I remove those if/else block along with @: the code works just like before so how do I include html code in a C# block and C# code in html block in the following view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ecomm2.Models.HomeSearchResultsViewModel>

@{

    if (Model.Count < 1) 
    {
        @:<p style="color:red">Item not found</p>
    }
    else
    {

    @:<table style="background-color:#f7f7f7;width:100%; border:0px solid black;">   

    foreach (var item in Model) {
        @:<tr style="border:1px solid #bbb9b9;">
          @:  <td style="width:177px;">
              @:  <img src="~/Content/images/meter.jpeg"  alt="Alternate Text" style="height:177px;width:177px;padding:10px;"/>

            @:</td>
            @:<td style="width:100%;padding-left:2px;float:left;padding-top:20px;border:0px solid black;font-size:medium">
                <span>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductLineName, "GetProductDetails", "Product", new { id = item.Id }, new { }) <br />
              @:  </span>

                @:<span style="font-size:small">By @Html.ActionLink(item.BrandName, "GetProductByBrandName", new { id=item.BrandName})</span><br />

                @:<span style="font-size:x-small">
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.CategoryName, "GetProductsByCategoryName", new { id=item.CategoryName}) | Stock Count: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockCount)
               </span><br />


               @using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new { id=item.Id}))
                {
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default"/>
                    </fieldset>
                }

            </td>
            <td style="width:20%;color:#00b02f;font-weight:bold;padding-top:20px;float:none;padding-left:20px;">
                LKR: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListPrice)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    @:</table>
}       

}
```

Here is the original code that threw the error

> External component has thrown an exception.

[image]

Here is the original code

```
@model IEnumerable<ecomm2.Models.HomeSearchResultsViewModel>


    @if (Model.Count < 1) 
    {
        <p style="color:red">Item not found</p>
    }
    else
    {

    <table style="background-color:#f7f7f7;width:100%; border:0px solid black;">   

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr style="border:1px solid #bbb9b9;">
            <td style="width:177px;">
                <img src="~/Content/images/meter.jpeg"  alt="Alternate Text" style="height:177px;width:177px;padding:10px;"/>

            </td>
            <td style="width:100%;padding-left:2px;float:left;padding-top:20px;border:0px solid black;font-size:medium">
                <span>
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductLineName, "GetProductDetails", "Product", new { id = item.Id }, new { }) <br />
                </span>

                <span style="font-size:small">By @Html.ActionLink(item.BrandName, "GetProductByBrandName", new { id=item.BrandName})</span><br />

                <span style="font-size:x-small">
                    @Html.ActionLink(item.CategoryName, "GetProductsByCategoryName", new { id=item.CategoryName}) | Stock Count: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StockCount)
               </span><br />


               @using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new { id=item.Id}))
                {
                    <fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-default"/>
                    </fieldset>
                }

            </td>
            <td style="width:20%;color:#00b02f;font-weight:bold;padding-top:20px;float:none;padding-left:20px;">
                LKR: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListPrice)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
}
```

In the Index view it calls the partial page "_SearchResultList" [here is the video that shows all](https://youtu.be/t0qbij-77jA)

Comment: Why do you have all those `@:` code? None of those seem necessary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i was experimenting : )

Comment: @StephenMuecke the initial error occured when i inject an if/else block it thrown the error "External Component throws an exception" so i i tried some @s to it

Comment: I can't see any thing in your view that would necessitate the need for using `@:`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i will post a video in a minute so the error will be shown

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have updated my original post with the original code of the partialview and the video that shows the error

Comment: You should put a breakpoint in the partial view :) `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a property `Count` so your `if` block throws an exception. Use `@if (Model.Count() < 1)` instead (of `@if (Model.Any())`. And remove all the `@:` code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you found it!, champ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your `@:` code is necessary. The reason you get the exception is that `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a property `Count` so your `if` block throws an exception. Change you code to

```
if (Model.Count() < 1)
```

of better, use

```
if (Model.Any())
```

and swap the code in the `if` and `else` blocks

Comment: i want to extend this if you don't mind, i have partial view with a form that does ajax calls and the form is loaded to index view of another controller. Ajax sends data to my ajax action method but it does not place the return partial view of "_SearchResultList" on the index page. That updating div area is on the index page. are there any reasons why this fails?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. You will need to ask a new question with the relevant code (including the script and the method that it calls). I'll keep a eye out for it.